# Load an RTF file from resources to a RichTextBox in a WPF application

Tags: .net, wpf, resources, richtextbox, rtf

I am trying to load the content of an RTF file, which I have put inside resources (through `Project->Properties->Resources->Add File`).

I want to load `Agreement.rtf`'s content to a `RichTextBox` and I have tried the following:

```
Dim stream As Stream
stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("Agreement").GetType(), "IOpzioni.Agreement.rtf")
RichTextBox1.SelectAll()

RichTextBox1.Selection.Load(stream, DataFormats.Rtf)
```

also

```
   stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(My.Resources.Agreement.GetType(), "IOpzioni.Agreement.rtf")
```

`IOpzioni` is my default namespace (I have double checked that).

Nothing seems to work. What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I achieved this in a somewhat simple way in my WPF application. See my blog here:
http://devdare.blogspot.com/2014/03/wpf-loading-rtf-document-in-richtextbox.html

1. In your WPF projects, add a `Resources.resx` file (if it's not already
   there)
2. Add your `RTFDoc.rtf` in your Resources.resx file
3. Along with your `Resources.resx` file, there would be code behind file: `Resources.Designer.cs`. Open it and copy its namespace and class name. In my case it is `Surf.Resources.Resource1`

I used this to load the RTF resource in my WPF `RichTextBox` control. Here are the lines from the code behind:

```
using Surf.Resources;

void Surface_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{             
    var stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(Resource1.RTFDoc));
    RichTextBox1.Selection.Load(stream, DataFormats.Rtf);
}
```

Surf is my project name here. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing is to ensure the file is an embedded resource of the project.  Then ensure the resource name of the file is the folder location, dot separated starting at the root of the project.  For example, let's say I have project Test where the resources folder is under Runtime\Source, then I should set the name as Test.Runtime.Source.Resources.Agreement.rtf.

Then just call this method (it's in C# but you can convert it), send your name, in this example "Test.Runtime.Source.Resources.Agreement.rtf" to read the contents:

```
  public static string GetResourceByName(string resource)
  {
     Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
     StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resource));
     return reader.ReadToEnd();
  }
```